# whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift4

I am developing a game and I am trying to move from my game scene to my view controller but it gives me the error:

> Warning: Attempt to present <Breakout.GameViewController: 0x7f8874d19ed0> on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!.

My game is set up so I do level 1 and finish it then it takes me to the vc where I can do level 1. That works, but then when I finish level 2 and try to go back to the vc, it does not work and gives me the error.

I have looked at other posts but nothing has directly linked to this.

My Game Scene Controller:

```
class Level1: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var ball:SKSpriteNode!
    var paddle:SKSpriteNode!
    var scoreLabel:SKLabelNode!
    var score:Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            scoreLabel.text = "Score:\(score)"
        }
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        ball = self.childNode(withName: "Ball") as! SKSpriteNode
        paddle = self.childNode(withName: "Paddle") as! SKSpriteNode
        scoreLabel = self.childNode(withName: "Score") as! SKLabelNode

        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 50, dy: 50))
        ball.physicsBody?.mass=0.1
        let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: (view.scene?.frame)!)
        border.friction = 0

        self.physicsBody = border
        ball.physicsBody?.mass = 0.09
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            paddle.position.x = touchLocation.x
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            paddle.position.x = touchLocation.x
        }
    }


    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let bodyAName = contact.bodyA.node?.name
        let bodyBName = contact.bodyB.node?.name

        if bodyAName == "Ball" && bodyBName == "Brick" || bodyAName == "Brick" && bodyBName == "Ball"{
            if bodyAName == "Brick" {
                contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
                score += 1
            } else if bodyBName == "Brick" {
                contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()
                score += 1
            }
        }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if (score == 9) {
            scoreLabel.text = "You Won!"
            self.view?.isPaused = true
            sleep(2)
            let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameViewController")
            self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            level1done = true
        }
        if (ball.position.y < paddle.position.y) {
            scoreLabel.text = "You Lost!"
            self.view?.isPaused = true
            sleep(2)
            let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameViewController")
            self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to present your view controller in the main thread.             `DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true)
            }`

Comment: Why do you need to go to the view controller? Are you possibly using a UIKit view as a game menu or something?

Comment: Yes The VC is the main menu